# Why doesn't my program call my methods?

Tags: java, static-methods

java methods statithing but I can't seem to get my while statement on line 56 to call my methods properly.  Is there something that I'm doing wrong?  I am very new to Java so any sort of help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GradeCalculator { 
    static String fileInput;
    static double totalGrade;
    static int scoreCount= 0;
    static double classAverage;
    static double score;
    static double testScore;
    static double averageScore;
    static int numberOfStudents = 0;
    static char letterGrade;
    static String fileOutput;
    static String nameOfStudent;
    static int numberCount;
    static int numberCalculatedStudents;
    static double average = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //Welcome   

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to the Grade Calculator!  This program will\n" +
                                                " calculate the average percentage of 5 test scores that\n"+
                                                " are given in a given file once these scores are\n"+
                                                " averaged it will give the student a letter grade.","Welcome!",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    fileInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of the input file you wish to use for this program."
                                            ,"Input File",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    fileOutput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of the output file you wish to use for this program."
                                            ,"Output File",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    //preparing text files
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (fileOutput);                                         
    File inFile = new File (fileInput);

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileInput));
    outFile.println("Student Name   Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4   Test5   Average Grade");

    while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
        nameOfStudent = reader.next();
        outFile.printf("%n%n%s",nameOfStudent);
        numberOfStudents++;
        score = reader.nextDouble();
        calculateAverage(score);
        calculateGrade(averageScore);
        outFile.printf("                                %.2f   ", averageScore);
        outFile.println("                                                               "+letterGrade);
    }
    classAverage = classAverage/numberCalculatedStudents;       
    outFile.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nClass average for "+ numberCalculatedStudents + "of" + numberOfStudents + "is" + classAverage);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The report has successfully been completed and written into the file of " + fileOutput +"."
                                                    +" The class average is " + classAverage + ". Please go to the output file for the complete report.");  
    outFile.close();
    }

    public static void calculateAverage(double score) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileInput));
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (fileOutput);
        while (reader.hasNextDouble() && numberCount <= 5 ) {
            score = reader.nextDouble();
            numberCount++;
        if (score >= 0 & score <= 100) {
                outFile.printf("%10.2f",score);
            scoreCount++;
            average = score + average;
        }
        else
            outFile.printf("                **%.2f",score);
        }
        if (average!=0){
            numberCalculatedStudents++; 
            average = average/scoreCount;
            averageScore = average;
            classAverage = average + classAverage;
            }

            average = 0;
    }

    public static char calculateGrade (double averageScore) {

        if (averageScore >= 90 && averageScore <= 100)
            letterGrade = 'A';
        else if (averageScore < 90 && averageScore >= 80)
            letterGrade = 'B';
        else if (averageScore < 80 && averageScore >= 70)
            letterGrade = 'C';
        else if (averageScore < 70 && averageScore >= 60)
            letterGrade = 'D';
        else if (averageScore < 60 && averageScore >= 0)
            letterGrade = 'F';  
        else 
            letterGrade =' ';

        return letterGrade;
     }  
}
```

Comment: Which is line number 56?

Comment: Can't you tell us where the problem is instead of referencing to a line number?

Comment: i think its the line where he declares calulateAverage() method

Comment: Please take some time to properly format your post( especially the code - right indentation, spaces,etc,.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what line the problem is arising on, two issues jump out at me:

At the top of the while loop:

```
   if (score >= 0 & score <= 100)
    { outFile.printf("%10.2f",score);
        scoreCount++;
        average = score + average;
    }
    else
        outFile.printf("                **%.2f",score);}
```

You have a close bracket (`}`) after the else statement, but no open bracket. So that close bracket looks like its exiting the while loop before you want it to.

Second, it looks like you're trying to return something (namely a char) in your CalculateGrade method, but you have specified a return type of void on it, which means that even though you have a return statement, nothing gets returned when you call it. You don't show where you're calling that method, so I can't be sure this is causing a problem, but its certainly suspect. It seems like you want to use:

```
 public static char calculateAverage(double score) throws FileNotFoundException{
```

instead of `public static void calculateAverage(double score)...`

Also, is there a reason why all of these methods are static? Do you know what making something static means?

**EDIT (based on your comment):**

No. making a variable `static` makes it a "class variable", which means that only one of them exists for all objects of that class. To illustrate:

If you have a class like this:

```
class test {
static int id;
}
```

And you run the following code:

```
    test t1 = new test();
    test t2 = new test();

    t1.id = 4;
    t2.id = 8;

    System.out.println(t1.id);
```

it will print 8. This is because, since id is a `static` variable changing it on any object of the class will cause it to change for every other object of the class.

This is as opposed to an "instance variable" one of which exists for every object of the class. To make `id` an instance variable, simply remove the `static` keyword. If you do so and run the same code, it will print 4, because changing an instance variable of t2 has no effect on t1.

Make sense?